# Memory leak on one system but not on another

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, opencv

I have an application that I've build on my computer. It uses Qt and OpenCV. It's build for 64 bit. I've written it in Visual Studio 2013 and then created an installer with InstallForge (build for win7, 8, 10).
Beforehand I've ran `windeployqt` for my exe and included everything from that into the installer as well as `opencv_world300.dll`. Installing the application works fine, on my system (win7) and on the other system(win10). That other system doesn't have an installation of qt and opencv.

In the program I have a couple of steps. First I drag and drop an image from outside, then I do some selection stuff (dragging and resizing of rects) with image in the background (marking things). To this point this is all Qt. In the next step I want to resize the given image to `X * 800` where X is depending on the aspect ratio. This is where the crash happens on the other system.

I added my exe to WinDbg on the other system and ran the Debugger. Result is below.

```
CommandLine: "C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\FaceModifier.exe"
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00007ff7`5b020000 00007ff7`5b10f000   FaceModifier.exe
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c6f80000 00007ff8`c7141000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`a7b00000 00007ff8`a7b6d000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\verifier.dll
Page heap: pid 0x8B0: page heap enabled with flags 0x3.
AVRF: FaceModifier.exe: pid 0x8B0: flags 0x81643027: application verifier enabled
ModLoad: 00007ff8`a99a0000 00007ff8`a99dd000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\vrfcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`a40e0000 00007ff8`a414c000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\vfbasics.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c46f0000 00007ff8`c479d000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c3630000 00007ff8`c3818000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c44f0000 00007ff8`c4597000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c4450000 00007ff8`c44ed000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`52f80000 00000000`5343a000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\Qt5Core.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c66c0000 00007ff8`c6816000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c6d80000 00007ff8`c6f06000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c4e30000 00007ff8`c638c000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c40a0000 00007ff8`c40e3000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\cfgmgr32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c3820000 00007ff8`c3e64000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\windows.storage.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c6830000 00007ff8`c6aad000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\combase.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c6d20000 00007ff8`c6d7b000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c65a0000 00007ff8`c66bc000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c6bc0000 00007ff8`c6d03000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c4d60000 00007ff8`c4e21000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`95410000 00007ff8`95945000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\Qt5Gui.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`52a50000 00000000`52f7a000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\Qt5Widgets.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`933f0000 00007ff8`95410000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\opencv_world300.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`a3440000 00007ff8`a34e6000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP120.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`a0160000 00007ff8`a024f000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`928f0000 00007ff8`92e58000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mfc120u.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c43f0000 00007ff8`c4442000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c4650000 00007ff8`c468b000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`aaed0000 00007ff8`aaef9000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVFW32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b14a0000 00007ff8`b14c0000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AVIFIL32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`ac6a0000 00007ff8`ac6b8000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AVICAP32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b1200000 00007ff8`b12aa000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.10586.0_none_396e892957c7fb25\COMCTL32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c1f20000 00007ff8`c1fb6000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UxTheme.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c17f0000 00007ff8`c1813000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`bb0f0000 00007ff8`bb10c000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSACM32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c17c0000 00007ff8`c17ec000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c3f20000 00007ff8`c3f8a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c3610000 00007ff8`c361f000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel.appcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c42c0000 00007ff8`c4375000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\shcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c35c0000 00007ff8`c360b000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\powrprof.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c35a0000 00007ff8`c35b4000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\profapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c4380000 00007ff8`c43eb000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`bda90000 00007ff8`bdaab000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`527f0000 00000000`52a50000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\icuin53.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`52640000 00000000`527eb000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\icuuc53.dll
ModLoad: 0000026f`35f60000 0000026f`373ea000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\icudt53.dll
(8b0.13e4): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ff8`c704aa60 cc              int     3
0:000> g
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c0340000 00007ff8`c034a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\version.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c3040000 00007ff8`c304b000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL
Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
ModLoad: 00007ff8`a79d0000 00007ff8`a7af5000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\platforms\qwindows.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c1470000 00007ff8`c1492000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c4c00000 00007ff8`c4d5a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c45a0000 00007ff8`c4647000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\clbcatq.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b78d0000 00007ff8`b791a000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\dataexchange.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c11c0000 00007ff8`c1468000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d11.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c0c70000 00007ff8`c0d12000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\dxgi.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c19a0000 00007ff8`c1a83000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\dcomp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c20c0000 00007ff8`c21c0000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\twinapi.appcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c34d0000 00007ff8`c34f9000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\bcrypt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`ba140000 00007ff8`ba151000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qdds.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`ba130000 00007ff8`ba13d000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qgif.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b9be0000 00007ff8`b9bef000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qicns.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b9bd0000 00007ff8`b9bdd000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qico.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`ac6d0000 00007ff8`ac74b000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qjp2.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b29a0000 00007ff8`b29df000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`ab2e0000 00007ff8`ab328000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qmng.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b9bc0000 00007ff8`b9bcc000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qsvg.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`525e0000 00000000`52631000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\Qt5Svg.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b9bb0000 00007ff8`b9bbc000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qtga.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`ab280000 00007ff8`ab2dc000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qtiff.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b5aa0000 00007ff8`b5aaa000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qwbmp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`a7970000 00007ff8`a79cd000   C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\imageformats\qwebp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b6dc0000 00007ff8`b7034000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.10586.0_none_8c15ae12515e1c22\comctl32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c0ab0000 00007ff8`c0c61000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`ba110000 00007ff8`ba126000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OpenCL.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`8ef30000 00007ff8`91cfa000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\amdocl64.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c47b0000 00007ff8`c4bd9000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`aba00000 00007ff8`abb29000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`aa650000 00007ff8`aa7dc000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b5910000 00007ff8`b593e000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`ab900000 00007ff8`ab9fa000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DDRAW.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`ba100000 00007ff8`ba108000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DCIMAN32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`aaf00000 00007ff8`ab041000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\atiadlxx.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c6d10000 00007ff8`c6d18000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c14a0000 00007ff8`c1626000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c2d00000 00007ff8`c2d1f000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c1710000 00007ff8`c1723000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`bd7c0000 00007ff8`bd7f8000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c2070000 00007ff8`c2097000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c3f90000 00007ff8`c3fe5000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINTRUST.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c3620000 00007ff8`c3630000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`c40f0000 00007ff8`c42b8000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`8d470000 00007ff8`8ef29000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\amdocl12cl64.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff8`b4a00000 00007ff8`b4a2c000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\atig6txx.dll


=======================================
VERIFIER STOP 0000000000000900: pid 0x8B0: A heap allocation was leaked. 

    0000026F45B0CD20 : Address of the leaked allocation. Run !heap -p -a <address> to get additional information about the allocation.
    0000026F2F1DC4D0 : Address to the allocation stack trace. Run dps <address> to view the allocation stack.
    0000026F45A7FFD8 : Address of the owner dll name. Run du <address> to read the dll name.
    00007FF8B4A00000 : Base of the owner dll. Run .reload <dll_name> = <address> to reload the owner dll. Use 'lm' to get more information about the loaded and unloaded modules.


=======================================
This verifier stop is continuable.
After debugging it use `go' to continue.

=======================================

(8b0.13e4): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
vrfcore!VerifierStopMessageEx+0x6d0:
00007ff8`a99a2190 cc              int     3
0:000> !heap -p -a 0000026F45B0CD20
    address 0000026f45b0cd20 found in
    _DPH_HEAP_ROOT @ 26f30791000
    in busy allocation (  DPH_HEAP_BLOCK:         UserAddr         UserSize -         VirtAddr         VirtSize)
                             26f3ee909c0:      26f45b0cd20              2e0 -      26f45b0c000             2000
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\atig6txx.dll - 
          ? atig6txx!XopOpenLinkedAdapter+26b8
    00007ff8c70125c7 ntdll!RtlDebugAllocateHeap+0x0000000000000047
    00007ff8c6fa7cce ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeap+0x00000000000000ee
    00007ff8c6fa5c5f ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeapInternal+0x000000000000064f
    00007ff8a99ac016 vrfcore!VfCoreRtlAllocateHeap+0x0000000000000036
    00007ff8a40f04a8 vfbasics!AVrfpRtlAllocateHeap+0x0000000000000108
    00007ff8b4a15e27 atig6txx!XopOpenLinkedAdapter+0x000000000000c46f
    00007ff8b4a15cf7 atig6txx!XopOpenLinkedAdapter+0x000000000000c33f
    00007ff8b4a06e4b atig6txx!SetThunkProxyBypassMode+0x0000000000002d0f
    00007ff8b4a04124 atig6txx!GetD3DKMTProcAddress+0x0000000000000038
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\amdocl64.dll - 
    00007ff88efa6b2a amdocl64+0x0000000000076b2a
    00007ff88efa6591 amdocl64+0x0000000000076591
    00007ff88ef88cfb amdocl64+0x0000000000058cfb
    00007ff88ef8f181 amdocl64+0x000000000005f181
    00007ff88efa119b amdocl64+0x000000000007119b
    00007ff88f17f610 amdocl64!clSetKernelExecInfo+0x000000000002d380
    00007ff88f17b66b amdocl64!clSetKernelExecInfo+0x00000000000293db
    00007ff88f15f7e2 amdocl64!clSetKernelExecInfo+0x000000000000d552
    00007ff88f153225 amdocl64!clSetKernelExecInfo+0x0000000000000f95
    00007ff88f144c67 amdocl64!clIcdGetPlatformIDsKHR+0x0000000000000027
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OpenCL.dll - 
    00007ff8ba1110c5 OpenCL+0x00000000000010c5
    00007ff8ba1133b1 OpenCL!clWaitForEvents+0x0000000000000191
    00007ff8c6fd44b1 ntdll!RtlRunOnceExecuteOnce+0x0000000000000091
    00007ff8c3683d4a KERNELBASE!InitOnceExecuteOnce+0x000000000000000a
    00007ff8ba1132ae OpenCL!clWaitForEvents+0x000000000000008e
    00007ff8ba111042 OpenCL+0x0000000000001042
    00007ff8ba112cdc OpenCL!clGetPlatformIDs+0x000000000000001c
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\opencv_world300.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files\FaceModifier\opencv_world300.dll - 
    00007ff8941d37ad opencv_world300!cv::ocl::haveOpenCL+0x000000000000002d
    00007ff8941dbefe opencv_world300!cv::ocl::useOpenCL+0x000000000000002e
    00007ff8943a2f46 opencv_world300!cv::resize+0x0000000000000296
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for FaceModifier.exe
    00007ff75b04379e FaceModifier!Normalizer::normalize+0x000000000000054e
    00007ff75b0b4d00 FaceModifier!FaceModifier::processImage+0x00000000000003b0
    00007ff75b041bcc FaceModifier!FaceModifier::confirmSelection+0x00000000000000fc
```

As far as I can tell there is a problem with `cv::resize` which I call in `Normalizer::normalize`. I had a look at it and it is recommended to not use the same cv::Mat for input and output so I changed that, but still it crashes on that point. My function looks like this (the resize is about in the middle):

```
// part of the header:
private:
    const int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 800;
    const float OFFSET_SCALE = 0.05f;

cv::Mat Normalizer::normalize(cv::Mat source, std::vector<cv::Rect> &rectAreas, std::vector<cv::Vec3i> &eyes, std::vector<cv::Point> &chin)
{
    /*
        rectAreas:
        0: faceRect
        1: mouth
        2: brow left
        3: brow right
        4: nose
    */

    // complete face
    cv::Rect faceArea = rectAreas[0];

    int offsetX = cvRound(OFFSET_SCALE * faceArea.width);   // offset x of rect to be copied to the left (to get a small area around the face)
    int offsetY = cvRound(OFFSET_SCALE * faceArea.height);  // offset y of rect to be copied to the top (...)
    int x = faceArea.x - offsetX;                           // for calculating if rect for copying is fully inside source, fill with black pixels otherwise
    int y = faceArea.y - offsetY;                           // ...  
    int width = faceArea.width + 2 * offsetX;               // width of rect to be copied
    int height = faceArea.height + 2 * offsetY;             // height of rect to be copied
    cv::Rect offsetRect(x, y, width, height);               // create rect that will be copied from source

    // check if source = bounding rect
    // if true: black border
    int deltaX = 0, deltaY = 0;
    if (x < 0)                                              // if offsetRect is not fully in source, get difference, that will be filled with black pixels
    {
        offsetRect.x = 0;                                   // if black pixels are needed, adjust offsetRect to not start at negative coordinates
        deltaX = std::abs(x);                               // deltaX black pixels on x axis
    }
    if (y < 0)
    {
        offsetRect.y = 0;
        deltaY = std::abs(y);                               // deltaY black pixels on y axis
    }

    cv::Mat output;
    cv::Mat temp = cv::Mat::zeros(height + deltaY, width + deltaX, source.type());

    // same size as offsetRect, starting position at deltaX:deltaY in output
    cv::Rect targetRect(deltaX, deltaY, offsetRect.width, offsetRect.height);
    source(offsetRect).copyTo(temp(targetRect));

    // resize to X * IMAGE_HEIGHT (= 800)
    float aspectRatio = (float)temp.size().height / (float)temp.size().width;
    int scaledWidth = cvRound(IMAGE_HEIGHT / aspectRatio);

    cv::resize(temp, output, cv::Size(scaledWidth, IMAGE_HEIGHT), 0, 0, cv::INTER_CUBIC);
    temp.release();
    temp = NULL;

    // adjust eye centers

    /*
         offsetRect edge - delta      output edge                   offsetRect edge - delta      output edge
         -----------------------  =  -------------   #########      -----------------------  =  -------------
            old coord - margin         new coord                        old radius               new radius
    */

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        eyes[i][0] = cvRound((scaledWidth * (eyes[i][0] - offsetRect.x)) / (float)(offsetRect.width - deltaX));
        eyes[i][1] = cvRound((IMAGE_HEIGHT * (eyes[i][1] - offsetRect.y)) / (float)(offsetRect.height - deltaY));
        eyes[i][2] = cvRound((scaledWidth * eyes[i][2]) / (float)(offsetRect.width - deltaX));
        //std::cout << i << ": " << eyes[i][0] << ":" << eyes[i][1] << " " << eyes[i][2] << std::endl;
    }

    // adjust rect areas

    rectAreas[0].x = deltaX;
    rectAreas[0].y = deltaY;
    rectAreas[0].width = output.size().width - deltaX;
    rectAreas[0].height = output.size().height - deltaY;

    /*
        offsetRect edge - delta      output edge
        -----------------------  =  -------------
           old edge                   new egde
    */

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
    {
        rectAreas[i].x = cvRound((scaledWidth * (rectAreas[i].x - offsetRect.x)) / (float)(offsetRect.width - deltaX));
        rectAreas[i].y = cvRound((IMAGE_HEIGHT * (rectAreas[i].y - offsetRect.y)) / (float)(offsetRect.height - deltaY));
        rectAreas[i].width = cvRound((scaledWidth * rectAreas[i].width) / (float)(offsetRect.width - deltaX));
        rectAreas[i].height = cvRound((IMAGE_HEIGHT * rectAreas[i].height) / (float)(offsetRect.height - deltaY));
    }

    // adjust chin points
    for (int i = 0; i < chin.size(); i++)
    {
        chin[i].x = cvRound((scaledWidth * (chin[i].x - offsetRect.x)) / (float)(offsetRect.width - deltaX));
        chin[i].y = cvRound((IMAGE_HEIGHT * (chin[i].y - offsetRect.y)) / (float)(offsetRect.height - deltaY));
    }

    return output;
}
```

Seems like there is still something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Did you run the debug build under debugger? If you cannot have it on that machine, [remote debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) might be an option. Another way is to release a build with debug symbols, make it run on remote machine and grabbing the crash dump, this time with some meaningful information.

Comment: Your question can be summarized as "my program crashes, here's some meaningless gibberish consisting of random crash dumps and other runtime diagnostics, why does my program crash?" Answer: because there's a bug somewhere in your code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So, if it is a bug in the code, why does it work on one system, but hard crashes on another?

Comment: The backtrace suggests an exception is thrown, so make sure to catch all exceptions. Maybe also set a breakpoint at throw in your debugger (in gdb that'd be called *catch point* and enabled with "catch throw").

Comment: @Drop I think I did what you meant with your first question. I added my exe to WinDbg and did Debug>Go. I do actually get a `heap allocation was leaked` and `!heap -p -a` at some point gives a warning about unverified checksum for my exe and one of my function, but an error on `cv:resize` which I use in that function. I had a look what could cause that and it's recommended to do `cv::resize(src, dst, ...)` and not `cv::resize(src, src, ...)`. I did the later, so I will try it now with a change to the first.

Comment: @Drop Ok, I changed my code, but still I get this error. I've added the log from WinDbg and my function to the question.

Comment: I mean real debugger. Like one in Visual Studio. With breakpoints, watches, call stack gathered conveniently in one place. WinDbg is a mess.

Comment: @Drop Hmm, ok, will have to do that with a remote then. On my computer it doesn't throw anything.

Comment: Just because "it work on one system" does not mean it's bug-free. I found plenty of bugs in my code after porting it from Linux to FreeBSD. They were typically race conditions that did not exhibit themselves on Linux due to the behavior of Linux's thread scheduler. You have one or more bugs somewhere in your code. Your only option is to find them and fix them.